# Image upload in Django, namerror

Tags: python, django, image, file-upload

Getting NameError (global name FileUploadHandler not defined). Here is the model:

```
class FileUploadHandler(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="wiki/static/")
```

And the view:

```
def image_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            FileUploadHandler(request.FILES['image'])
            return render_to_response('wiki/gallery.html')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()
     return render_to_response('wiki/gallery.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your view file, type:

```
from models import FileUploadHandler
```

This is assuming you have the standard `views.py` and `models.py` file structure where both are in the same directory.

Comment: It happens to everyone. Just remember that a `NameError` typically means you're using a name for something that Python has no idea how to interpret. The culprit is likely to be a missing import.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not getting the error, but the file isn't showing up in the specified folder. I tried adding form.save() to the view but its indicating that the object doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: Well this question has effectively been answered. If you run into a problem subsequent to the resolution here, then it's best practice to post a separate question.

Comment: even better (more correct): `from .models import FileUploadHandler` - explicit relative imports is the best practice.